# Grafana alerting Error: tsdb.HandleRequest()

Tags: time-series, grafana, grafana-alerts

I am using Grafana version: v6.7.3 (a04ef6cefc)

After creating a new alert in my widget dashboard, I am seeing the following error:

> **Error: tsdb.HandleRequest() error bad_response: readObjectStart: expect { or n, but found <, error found in #5 byte of ...|**

The error looks to be triggering similar to an alert. Has anyone else encountered something similar to this?

[image]

the Error JSON output

```
{
  "firing": true,
  "state": "pending",
  "conditionEvals": " = true",
  "timeMs": "24.602ms",
  "error": "tsdb.HandleRequest() error bad_response: readObjectStart: expect { or n, but found <, error found in #5 byte of ...|    <!DOCTYPE h|..., bigger context ...|    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transi|...",
  "logs": [
    {
      "message": "Condition[0]: Query",
      "data": {
        "from": 1637767915735,
        "queries": [
          {
            "refId": "A",
            "model": {
              "expr": "sum by (code, app_kubernetes_io_instance)(rate(nginx_server_requests{app_kubernetes_io_instance=~\"vue-frontend\",code=~\"4..\"}[1m]))",
              "format": "time_series",
              "hide": false,
              "instant": false,
              "interval": "",
              "intervalFactor": 1,
              "legendFormat": "{{code}} on {{app_kubernetes_io_instance}}",
              "refId": "A"
            },
            "datasource": {
              "id": 14,
              "name": "somesomain.com"
            },
            "maxDataPoints": 0,
            "intervalMs": 0
          }
        ],
        "to": 1637768215735
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70586927/how-to-add-the-kafka-exporter-as-a-data-source-to-grafana