# Kiali is not working with VictoriaMetricsHello

Tags: istio, kiali, victoriametrics

Was anyone was able to make kiali visualise mesh using VictoriaMetrics instead of Prometheus?

When I use [prometheus](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/samples/addons/prometheus.yaml) and [kiali](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/samples/addons/kiali.yaml) setup from istio samples then Mesh Visualisation works.

But when I replace prometheus with Victoria Metrics (agent, select, insert, storage) then kiali simply showing empty graph.

I have checked that both Prometheus and Victoria Metrics have the same **istio_requests_total** metric.

But when I use Victoria Metrics select URL in spec.external_services.prometheus.url the graph comes empty.

```
apiVersion: kiali.io/v1alpha1
kind: Kiali
metadata:
  name: kiali
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  auth:
    strategy: anonymous
  external_services:
    istio:
      config_map_name: istio-1-14
      url_service_version: http://istiod-1-14:15014/version
    prometheus:
      url: http://vmselect-example-vmcluster-persistent.poc.svc.cluster.local:8481/select/0/prometheus/
```

In logs I see two errors related to the fact that vm-select does not have corresponding endpoints

```
2022-07-15T19:25:13Z ERR Failed to fetch Prometheus configuration:     bad_response: readObjectStart: expect { or n, but found r, error found      in #1 byte of ...|remoteAddr:|..., bigger context ...|remoteAddr:      "10.4.34.83:57468"; requestURI: /select|... 
2022-07-15T19:25:13Z ERR Failed to fetch Prometheus flags: bad_response: readObjectStart:     expect { or n, but found r, error found in #1 byte of     ...|remoteAddr:|..., bigger context ...|remoteAddr:     "10.4.34.83:57468"; requestURI: /select|...
```

and multiple warnings

```
 2022-07-15T19:35:28Z WRN Skipping      {destination_canonical_revision="v1",     destination_canonical_service="microservice",      destination_cluster="Kubernetes",     destination_service="microservice.poc.svc.cluster.local",      destination_service_name="microservice",     destination_service_namespace="poc",     destination_workload="microservice",     destination_workload_namespace="poc", request_protocol="http",     response_code="200", response_flags="-", source_canonical_revision="latest",     source_canonical_service="istio-ingressgateway-internal",  source_cluster="Kubernetes"}, missing expected TS labels
```

Here is my  VMPodScrape which I expect will take all metrics from all pods

```
apiVersion: operator.victoriametrics.com/v1beta1
kind: VMPodScrape
metadata:
  name: all-scrape
  namespace: poc
spec:
  podMetricsEndpoints:
    - scheme: http
      path: /stats/prometheus
      targetPort: 15090
  selector: {}
  namespaceSelector:
    any: true
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70586927/how-to-add-the-kafka-exporter-as-a-data-source-to-grafana

Answer (score 4):

Error messages don't look critical, in case of error kiali should use default values. As far as I understand, it tries to recognize scrape interval and retention based on prometheus configuration file and flags.

I think you have an issue with relabeling config, it drops labels required for kiali.

There is docs with needed labels by metric name:
https://kiali.io/docs/faq/general/#which-istio-metrics-and-attributes-are-required-by-kiali

I'd recommend check scrape config at VMAgent. Probably relabeling rules are outdated.

Comment: Thanks for you answer @f41gh7. In my config I do not have relabelling section at all. If I understand it correctly, then if no relabelling is done, then all labels will flow from istio through  victoriametrics to kiali?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. I've checked again error messages and metrics don't have 2 required labels: source_workload and source_workload_namespace . Probably Istio could add it with some magic.

Comment: Also, i suggest to execute non-aggregated request for istio metrics, like `istio_tcp_sent_bytes_total`. And check does it have source_workload and source_workload_namespace labels? If it has such labels, the issue could be related to the query requests, executed by kiali.

Answer (score 1):

For me I did not use the VMPodScrape,

I used the simplest VictoriaMetrics Single in Kubernetes via Helm charts based on the official guide (https://docs.victoriametrics.com/guides/k8s-monitoring-via-vm-single.html)
Note: I install install on "victoria-metric" namespace.

After the installation, I edit the configmap, which based on
**istio-1.17.1/samples/addons/prometheus.yaml** , the config map is as below.

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: vmsingle
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: victoria-metric
  labels:
    app: server
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: vmsingle
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: victoria-metrics-single
    helm.sh/chart: victoria-metrics-single-0.8.55
  name: vmsingle-victoria-metrics-single-server-scrapeconfig
  namespace: victoria-metric
data:
  scrape.yml: |2

    global:
      scrape_interval: 15s

    scrape_configs:
    - job_name: victoriametrics
      static_configs:
      - targets:
        - localhost:8428
    - bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
      job_name: kubernetes-apiservers
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: endpoints
      relabel_configs:
      - action: keep
        regex: default;kubernetes;https
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_namespace
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_name
        - __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name
      scheme: https
      tls_config:
        ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        insecure_skip_verify: true
    - bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
      job_name: kubernetes-nodes
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: node
      relabel_configs:
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
      - replacement: kubernetes.default.svc:443
        target_label: __address__
      - regex: (.+)
        replacement: /api/v1/nodes/$1/proxy/metrics
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_node_name
        target_label: __metrics_path__
      scheme: https
      tls_config:
        ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        insecure_skip_verify: true
    - bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
      job_name: kubernetes-nodes-cadvisor
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: node
      relabel_configs:
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
      - replacement: kubernetes.default.svc:443
        target_label: __address__
      - regex: (.+)
        replacement: /api/v1/nodes/$1/proxy/metrics/cadvisor
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_node_name
        target_label: __metrics_path__
      scheme: https
      tls_config:
        ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        insecure_skip_verify: true
    - honor_labels: true
      job_name: kubernetes-service-endpoints
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: endpoints
      relabel_configs:
      - action: keep
        regex: true
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape
      - action: drop
        regex: true
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape_slow
      - action: replace
        regex: (https?)
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scheme
        target_label: __scheme__
      - action: replace
        regex: (.+)
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_path
        target_label: __metrics_path__
      - action: replace
        regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
        replacement: $1:$2
        source_labels:
        - __address__
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_port
        target_label: __address__
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_param_(.+)
        replacement: __param_$1
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_namespace
        target_label: namespace
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_name
        target_label: service
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_node_name
        target_label: node
    - honor_labels: true
      job_name: kubernetes-service-endpoints-slow
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: endpoints
      relabel_configs:
      - action: keep
        regex: true
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape_slow
      - action: replace
        regex: (https?)
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scheme
        target_label: __scheme__
      - action: replace
        regex: (.+)
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_path
        target_label: __metrics_path__
      - action: replace
        regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
        replacement: $1:$2
        source_labels:
        - __address__
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_port
        target_label: __address__
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_param_(.+)
        replacement: __param_$1
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_namespace
        target_label: namespace
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_name
        target_label: service
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_node_name
        target_label: node
      scrape_interval: 5m
      scrape_timeout: 30s
    - honor_labels: true
      job_name: prometheus-pushgateway
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: service
      relabel_configs:
      - action: keep
        regex: pushgateway
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_probe
    - honor_labels: true
      job_name: kubernetes-services
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: service
      metrics_path: /probe
      params:
        module:
        - http_2xx
      relabel_configs:
      - action: keep
        regex: true
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_probe
      - source_labels:
        - __address__
        target_label: __param_target
      - replacement: blackbox
        target_label: __address__
      - source_labels:
        - __param_target
        target_label: instance
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
      - source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_namespace
        target_label: namespace
      - source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_name
        target_label: service
    - honor_labels: true
      job_name: kubernetes-pods
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: pod
      relabel_configs:
      - action: keep
        regex: true
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape
      - action: drop
        regex: true
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape_slow
      - action: replace
        regex: (https?)
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scheme
        target_label: __scheme__
      - action: replace
        regex: (.+)
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path
        target_label: __metrics_path__
      - action: replace
        regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
        replacement: $1:$2
        source_labels:
        - __address__
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port
        target_label: __address__
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_param_(.+)
        replacement: __param_$1
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_namespace
        target_label: namespace
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_name
        target_label: pod
      - action: drop
        regex: Pending|Succeeded|Failed|Completed
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_phase
    - honor_labels: true
      job_name: kubernetes-pods-slow
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: pod
      relabel_configs:
      - action: keep
        regex: true
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape_slow
      - action: replace
        regex: (https?)
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scheme
        target_label: __scheme__
      - action: replace
        regex: (.+)
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path
        target_label: __metrics_path__
      - action: replace
        regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
        replacement: $1:$2
        source_labels:
        - __address__
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port
        target_label: __address__
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_param_(.+)
        replacement: __param_$1
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_namespace
        target_label: namespace
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_name
        target_label: pod
      - action: drop
        regex: Pending|Succeeded|Failed|Completed
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_phase
      scheme: https
      tls_config:
        ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        insecure_skip_verify: true
```

Here is my kiali configmap.

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  labels:
    version: v1.63.1
  name: kiali
  namespace: istio-system
data:
  config.yaml: |
    ...
    external_services:
      custom_dashboards:
        enabled: true
      istio:
        root_namespace: istio-system
      prometheus:
        url: http://vmsingle-victoria-metrics-single-server.victoria-metric.svc.cluster.local:8428/
```

Everything is working in my setup.

During my debug journey to make it work, you may port-forwrd the traffic to victoria_metric pod to see the debug WebUI

```
kubectl port-forward <victoria_metric_pod_name> 8428:8428
```

then access VictoriaMetric on http://localhost:8428/targets
[image: VictoriaMetric target page]
This page will list the scape target in here, if you configure victoria metric scape correctly, we should see "kubernetes-pods" job up and running.

Here is the Kiali graph in my setup.
[image]
Notice that in the Kiali pod, there is some error in the log ... but the graph is still showing up.